# Machine data not displaying every 15 Seconds

Tags: bash, shell

The following script is meant to output "vmstat" for example every 15 seconds, but for some reason it only does this if there's activity or when I kill the script, in other cases it just sits there.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh


ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "vmstat 15" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "iostat 15" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "mpstat 15" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill

today=`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S`

find /var/log/ -name data_collection -type d -exec mv /var/log/data_collection /home/Beer/"data_collection_${today}" \;

mkdir -p /var/log/data_collection

vmstat 15 | /home/Beer/./addtimestamp.pl > /var/log/data_collection/vm_stat &
iostat 15 | /home/Beer/./addtimestamp.pl > /var/log/data_collection/ios_stat &
mpstat 15 | /home/Beer/./addtimestamp.pl > /var/log/data_collection/mp_stat &
```

Im guessing the '&' symbol at the end has something to do with this, I only did this so I can execute each command at once.

Comment: You can change `grep -v grep | grep "vmstat 15"` to `grep "[v]mstat 15"`, it is slightly safer in matching.

Comment: When on Linux, you might want to check `pgrep` and `pkill`.

Comment: If you do have to grep, you don't need the grep `ps -ef | awk '/[v]mstat 15/{ print $2 }'`. had to add it, sorry =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perl script in the middle is probably [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html). Try the commands without the `| /home/Beer/./addtimestamp.pl`. If that resolves the issue try adding:

```
$| = 1;
```

to the perl script.